# What does this jQuery line do?

Tags: jquery

I have a line of jQuery code that is causing an error as I placed two periods in front of the b class. I am wondering how does jQuery interpret the following line? If I had only one period in front of b instead of two, I assume that jQuery interpret it as: "if class b exists within class a which exists in the parent of this, alert prompt hi".

```
if ( $(this).parent().find(".a ..b") ) {
  alert("hi");
});
```

Comment: Why are you using two periods ?

Comment: It was a typo I made but the code seemed to work despite the error. I'm just trying to correct it.

Comment: In your question you said you have put it yourself explicitly: `I placed two periods in front of the b class`

Comment: Yup, but that was a typo. But I solved the problem :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.a ..b` is an invalid selector and it will throw error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .
```

`.a .b` is the correct selector.

So `$(this).parent().find(".a .b")` will first fetch the direct parent node of `this`, then it will search for a descendant element with the `class="a"` and then another descendant element within with the `class="b"`, and if it finds it will alert `hi`.

Comment: So that means anything inside that if statement will never be executed due to the error?

Comment: @icu222much, yes, due to the error, the javascript interpreter simply stops executing your scripts.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Actually, not all scripts. When a `<script>` throws, the subsequent `<script>`'s still execute normally.

Comment: It throws on Google Chrome. The important thing is that this is a wrong and unsupported selector that, as we have seen, behaves differently between browsers, so it simply shouldn't be used if you care about cross browser compatibility of your site.

Answer (score 3):

That might depend on the browser. Both in Internet Explorer 9 and Firefox 10.0, the selector will just find nothing, and you get back an empty jQuery object.

As you are using the jQuery object as the condition in the `if`, the code inside the `if` will always run. A jQuery object is always a non-falsy value, so the condition will always be evaluated as `true`, regardless of whether jQuery found anything from your selector.

If you want to check if something was found, use the `length` property:

```
if ( $(this).parent().find(selector).length ) {
```

Comment: oh, i didn't realize it would return true. thank you... that actually helped me debug some more :)